# Change Alias of Distinct for sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using below query on my code that is

```
await to( mymodel.aggregate('cid', 'DISTINCT', {plain: false,where:{created_by:user.id}}));
```

and query out put on console is

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`cid`) AS `DISTINCT` FROM `mymodel` AS `mymodel` WHERE `mymodel`.`created_by` = 7;
```

I got below output that is

```
ids --------------- [ { DISTINCT: 9 }, { DISTINCT: 10 }, { DISTINCT: 11 } ]
```

I want to change the alias that is DISTINCT to id. How i do that like below

```
ids --------------- [ { id: 9 }, { id: 10 }, { id: 11 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `.aggregate()` supports aliasing fields however it's simple to turn this into a regular query instead.

```
await mymodel.findAll({
    attributes: [ [ Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', 'cid'), 'id' ] ],
    where: { created_by: user.id }
});
```

Here we're utilising `Sequelize.fn()` to create the `DISTINCT` on `cid` and using the array attribute notation to alias it to `id`. More info on this [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#attributes).